flutter: bybit create order signature error
A signature error occurs in bybit orders, but I don't know why.
This code was created by referring to various sites and API documents, so I hope you can help me figure out which part is wrong.
Note: The _createSign function works well in APIs that use get.
The server response is as follows:
{retCode: 10004, retMsg: Signature for this request is not valid., result: {}, retExtInfo: {}, time: 1712637062011}
String _createSign(String paramStr) {
  var apiSecret = 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX';
  var hmacSha256 = Hmac(sha256, apiSecret.codeUnits);
  return hmacSha256.convert(paramStr.codeUnits).toString();
}

void placeOrder() async {
  var url = 'https://api.bybit.com/v5/order/create';
  var data = {
    "category": "spot",
    "orderLinkId": "spot-test-01",
    "orderType": "Limit",
    "price": "Market",
    "qty": "1.0",
    "side": "Buy",
    "symbol": "XRPUSDT",
  };
  var param = json.encode(data);
  var timeStamp = '${DateTime.now().millisecondsSinceEpoch}';
  var window = '5000';
  var paramStr = '$timeStamp$_apiKey$window$param';
  http.Response response = await http.post(
    Uri.parse(url),
    headers: {
      'X-BAPI-API-KEY': _apiKey,
      'X-BAPI-TIMESTAMP': timeStamp,
      'X-BAPI-RECV-WINDOW': window,
      'X-BAPI-SIGN': _createSign(paramStr),
    },
    body: data,
  );

  if (response.statusCode == 200) {
    debugPrint('${json.decode(utf8.decode(response.bodyBytes))}');
  } else {
    debugPrint('response.statusCode: ${response.statusCode}');
  }
}

